# Как открыть якорную ссылку с отступом сверху?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Сверху сайта шапка с меню со свойствами "height: 80px", "background: #......" и "position: fixed".

В середине контентная часть со свойством "margin: 80px 0px 0px 0px" и заголовками с уникальными идентификаторами "id="...".

В меню шапки ссылки типа "href="#..." на заголовки в контентной части.

При активации ссылки фокус переходит к заголовку, но он отображается с самого верха страницы, под фоном шапки.

Я конечно догадываюсь, что сделал супер криво, но тем не менее, есть ли вариант перейти на ссылку со сдвигом фокуса от верха страницы в 80px?

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul, li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

hr {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #E7EBF0;
    color: #003366;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
    width: 1170px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background: #E7EBF0;
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.header__row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #003366;
}

.header__logo {
}

.header__image {
    height: 80px;
    width: 320px;
}

.header__catalog {
}

.header__nav {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.header__nav a {
    letter-spacing: 0.10em;
    height: 31px;
    color: #003366;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: normal;
    background-color: #E7EBF0;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: auto 5px;
}

.header__nav a:hover {
    color: #663366;
    background-color: #B1BDCD;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.header__nav a:focus {
    color: #663366;
    background-color: #B1BDCD;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.header__nav a:active {
    color: #660F57;
    background-color: #B1BDCD;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
}

.header__contacts {
}


.content {
    width: 100%;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    margin: 82px auto 20px;
}

.content__row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.content__about {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #003366;
}

.content__about-head {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 0px auto 0px 0px;
}

.content__triangle-top-left {

    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid #003366; 
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
}

.content__about-title {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: auto 0px;
}

.content__about-subtitle {
    margin: 5px;
    text-indent: 20px;
}

.content__about-end {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px auto;
}

.content__triangle-bot-right {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 50px solid #003366; 
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.content__about-second-title {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: italic;
    margin: auto;
}

.footer__row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-top: 2px solid #003366;
    height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>...</title>
        <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="wrapper">

            <header class="header">

                <div class="container">

                    <div class="header__row">

                        <a class="header__logo" href="../index.html">
                            <img class="header__image" src="..." alt="...">
                        </a>

                        <nav class="header__nav">
                            <a class="button-about" href="#about">Ссылка</a>
                            <a class="button-catalog" href="#catalog">...</a>
                            <a class="button-services" href="#services">...</a>
                            <a class="button-contacts" href="#contacts">...</a>
                        </nav>

                        <ul type="none" class="header__contacts">
                            <li>...</li>
                            <li>...</li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </header>
            
            <content class="content">

                <div class="container">

                    <div class="content__row">

                        <div class="content__about">

                            <div class="content__about-head">

                                <div class="content__triangle-top-left">
                                </div>

                                <p class="content__about-title">
                                    <a id="about">
                                    ID<br />
                                    <br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    1<br />
                                    </a>
                                </p>
                            
                            </div>
                            
                            <p class="content__about-subtitle">
                                
                            </p>

                            <div class="content__about-end">

                                <p class="content__about-second-title">
                                    ...<br />
                                    ...<br />
                                    ...<br />
                                </p>

                                <div class="content__triangle-bot-right">
                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </content>

            <footer class="footer">

                <div class="container">

                    <div class="footer__row">

                        <a class="footer__text">...</a>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </footer>
        
        </div>
            
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Что бы ***сохранить возможность прямого обращения по якорным ссылкам извне*** и при этом иметь возможность скроллить с их помощью к нужным частям документа можно сделать так:

```js
const handleClick = event => {
  event.preventDefault()  
  const headerOffset = 60 // полная высота header'a
  const contentAnchors = document.querySelectorAll(".anchor-hash-content")
  const href = event.target.getAttribute("href")
  const elementToScroll = Array.from(contentAnchors).filter(item => 
  item.getAttribute("href") === href) 
  const elementPosition = elementToScroll[0].offsetTop
  window.scrollTo({
    top: elementPosition - headerOffset,
    behavior: "smooth"
  })
}

document.querySelectorAll(".anchor-hash-header").forEach(item => 
item.addEventListener("click", handleClick))
// игнорирует клики по заголовкам, здесь только для примера 
document.querySelectorAll(".anchor-hash-content").forEach(item => 
item.addEventListener("click", event => event.preventDefault()))
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 20px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 20px;
}

.menu > span {
  margin-right: auto;
}

.menu > a {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.anchor-hash-content {
  display: block;
  margin: 100px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu"><span>Меню</span>
  <a class="anchor-hash-header" href="aaa">Anchor 1</a>
  <a class="anchor-hash-header" href="bbb">Anchor 2</a>
</div>

<a class="anchor-hash-content" href="aaa">Content 1</a>
<a class="anchor-hash-content" href="bbb">Content 2</a>
```

Для того что бы сдвигать заголовок ниже уровня header'a при открытии, как вариант, можно проверять URL при загрузке, и в случае якорей сдвигать заголовок в нужное (видимое) положение:

```
const scrollToHash = urlHash => {
  const headerOffset = 60 // полная высота header'a
  const contentAnchors = document.querySelectorAll(".anchor-hash-content")
  const elementToScroll = Array.from(contentAnchors).filter(item => 
      item.getAttribute("href") === urlHash)
  const elementPosition = elementToScroll[0].offsetTop
  window.scrollTo({ top: elementPosition - headerOffset })
}

(() => {
  const url = new URL(window.location)
  const urlHash = url.hash
  if (urlHash) {
    scrollToHash(urlHash.substr(1)) // убираем символ #
  }
})()
```

Comment: Благодарю за развёрнутый ответ! Однако, мне придётся вернуться к нему лишь после освоения js. На данный момент мои познания ограничиваются html+css. Надеюсь кому-нибудь сведущему в js ваши ответы пригодятся! А тем временем, помучил прилично гугл и все-таки нашел как решить свой вопрос при помощи только css. Да, возможно это своего рода костыль, не мне судить, но я рад, что для моей верстки это сработало. Добавил найденное решение в качестве ответа на свой вопрос. Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Сработало вот что:

```css
#about {
    padding-top: 80px;
    margin-top: -80px;
}
```

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, такое Вам понадобиться прописать для каждого названия/якоря?

Comment: Да, совершенно верно. На данном этапе вёрстки работает, надеюсь в будущем не поломается/забагуется. `#about,
#catalog,
#services,
#contacts {
    padding-top: 80px;
    margin-top: -80px;
}`